# AWS Cloud Formation RDS security group in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to add ingress rules to a security group for an RDS instance, but when I add them it says `The security group 'sg-14820a71' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-527a8037'`.

I have explicitly specified the VPC I want the security group in, it should not be using the default. Any idea on how to make it use the correct VPC?

```
"Resources": {
    "DbVpcSecurityGroup": {
        "DependsOn": ["VPC", "BeanstalkSecurityGroup"],
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "Security group for RDS DB Instance.",
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "VPC"
            },
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": 3306,
                    "ToPort": 3306,
                    "SourceSecurityGroupName": {
                        "Ref": "BeanstalkSecurityGroup"
                    }
                }]
        }
    }
}
```

It work fine with no ingress rules (an creating the manually in the GUI):

```
"Resources": {
    "DbVpcSecurityGroup": {
        "DependsOn": ["VPC", "BeanstalkSecurityGroup"],
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "Security group for RDS DB Instance.",
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "VPC"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

This is the beanstalk security group:

```
"BeanstalkSecurityGroup": {
    "DependsOn": ["VPC"],
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Allow the Elastic Beanstalk instances to access the NAT device",
        "VpcId": {
            "Ref": "VPC"
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: When working with vpc, you should use `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId` instead of `SourceSecurityGroupNam`. Also, Are you sure that the `BeanstalkSecurityGroup` and DbVpcSecurityGroup` belong to same VPC ?

Comment: @slayedbylucifer using `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId` fixed the issue thanks. Add an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: glad it helped. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working in VPC, we should always use **`Security Group ID`** instead of **`Security Group Name`**.

So in this case of CloudFormation, use `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId` instead of `SourceSecurityGroupName`